# AWS DMS Job: continue where it left off

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I am working with an AWS DMS Job that migrates data from Oracle to a MySQL database. While we already have everything setup, we want to make sure that if any unforeseen event happens during migration, that would cause the migration task to stop (e.g. network issues), the DMS job can pick up where it left off once we have restart it again. If it stopped when 80% of records have been migrated, it would do the remaining 20% once restarted and not start back to square one.

I did my due diligence and tried to research AWS documentation, all I found out how how to monitor the progress of the task and how to setup event subscriptions. Id there a way to set the DMS task to behave this way? is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of DMS task

**1.**DMS Full load (There is no resume in DMS).****

This means once DMS task is failed you have to restart the task .
But lets say you have 100 tables in this DMS task and task failed after loading 90 tables and 91st table loading was in progress .
In that case you can resume DMS task and DMS will skip 90 tables load but it will re-start 91st table .
Basically resume in Full load task means it can skip already loaded tables but can not resume in progress full load task .

**2.**DMS CDC Only (It supports resume)****

In this task you can very well resume as long as you have DMS recovery check point in place .
Even if DMS task is stopped for few days and you have recovery check point you can resume same task or create new task with recovery check point .

**3. DMS (Full load +CDC )**

In this type of task if full load is done and CDC in progress then you can resume task as CDC very well supports resume .

Some advice if that helps you doing safe migration

Be very careful about restart with Drop or truncate future  .If by mistake some one restart the task full data base will be dropped or tables can be truncated and there is no way to recover it .
If you have issue with big table better create many small dms task so that partially loaded data does not have to be cleaned up .

If you can elaborate your real issue may be i can suggest some way arround .

Comment: Thank you very much, didn’t know where to check to make sure resume on full load doesn’t try to resume a specific table that’s half loaded.